# Troubleshoot my outlet

Tags: receptacle, circuit

My fridge in the garage stopped working. The outlet had no  power, I replaced the outlet but still no power.

Here are some observations I made:

The lights sharing the same breaker switch turns on and off properly

Using the current detector on the old outlet before replacement gave slow beep, around 1 beep per second.

Using current detector on a normal functioning outlet gives rapid beep, maybe 5-6 per second

Current detector no beep at all in the new outlet.

I am mystified.

Could the wire to the outlet be bitten off by a rat or something?

Comment: Yes, rodent damage is a real issue. Had it happen to me, twice.

Comment: Are you comfortable taking the cover off the breaker panel? I have a feeling you will find an opened or burnt up wire where the hot or neutral wire lands on the breaker or neutral bar.  That's why NEC 2017 requires use of a torque screwdriver for setting screw torques.

Comment: Do you know where the lights on that breaker branch off the circuit at?

Comment: No I don’t know where they break off. Thinking I might need to buy one of those wire path finders... Monica if the breaker was burned the light sharing the same breaker wound not turn on at all.

Comment: Have you checked the rest of the outlets to see if any of them have a "test/reset"  button on them?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you jack you are amazing. I went thought every gfci outlet in my house and finally reset the one in my upstairs bathroom to get power back in my garage. They are on opposite sides of the house too. It’s only natural that I check it last after looking all day. Hope I Don’t find out who set up the wiring for my house.